# UICollectionViewController nested in a normal UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have added a `UICollectionView` into a normal ViewController (MainViewController), and than created a `UICollectionViewController` Subclass (CollectionViewController) in the ViewController and connected the `UICollectionView` outlet with the CollectionViewController object

```
_collectionViewController = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:_collectionView.collectionViewLayout];

_collectionView.dataSource = _collectionViewController;
_collectionView.delegate = _collectionViewController;
```

In the CollectionViewController I have setup an simple NSArray object and I show this one. This works as expected. But If I try to access the collectionview from the CollectionViewController via self.collectionview I am not able to access this one.

I dont know what I have to do, to also connect the collectionview.

I have build a sample ios-app it is available at: https://github.com/patricks/uicollectionview-problem

The method - (void)outputSelectedCell in the UICollectionViewController always shows, that there is nothing selected…

I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for updating your Github repo with the solution. Helped me figure this out after a full day of troubleshooting some problems I was seeing. I wish I could upvote you 100 times. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different collection views. One is the one you have an outlet to in the storyboard (_collectionView in MainViewController). The other is one you get automatically with a UICollectionViewController, which is the one you get when you log self.collectionView in CollectionViewController. The usual way to use a collection view with a UIViewController, is to make that controller the data source and delegate of the collection view, not be instantiating a UICollectionViewController. So, I would move all the collection view data source and delegate methods from CollectionViewController to MainViewController, and delete CollectionViewController -- there's really no reason to have that object.  Remember to set MainViewController as the delegate and data source for the collection view (which you can do in IB). You can define _collectionitems in the viewDidLoad method of MainViewController, and move the code in outputSelectedCell to testButtonPressed.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my problem. I always thought it would be better to put the UICollectionViewController into a separate class.

Comment: Now I figured out another problem… Whats the solution, if I want more UICollectionViews in the MainViewController?

Comment: @patrickS, you can put multiple collection views in the same controller, you just need to check which one is calling the data source and delegate methods. So, each of those needs an if-else clause  with something like "if ([collectionView isEqual:self.collectionView1])" else if ([collectionView isEqual:self.collectionView2]) etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, @rdelmar. It brought a frustrating day to a happy conclusion. :)